# Question on receiving first staked reward

Tags: ledger, delegating, rewards

I am new at staking and I delegated several thousand XTZ with Kraken using the Ledger Nano X.  It has been 43 days and nothing seems to have happened.  Is there something else I need to do to start receiving rewards?  Is 43 days a typical period of time to still see nothing back?  How do I check to make sure I have done everything correctly?  Thx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kraken, and all other exchanges, do not accept external delegations. You must hold your tokens within your Kraken account in order to receive rewards.

https://baking-bad.org/blog/2020/07/14/_1k-tezos-users-delegated-to-binance-and-kraken-directly-and-will-not-get-staking-rewards/

Unfortunately for you, Kraken has been using your delegation and is not obligated to pay you any rewards since you delegated externally.

You should find a new baker.

Comment: @Clann Please mark as answered if all is good!

Comment: I am really feeling like an idiot now...how exactly do I mark as answered?  Many thanks for your patience...and thanks again for taking the time to educate me.

Comment: @Clann There should be a checkmark icon available to you to click.

Comment: Found it and complete.  Thanks again for stepping me through it...